# YII2 how to handle condition as per login usertype?

Tags: php, yii2

[image]**vendorinfo.php** I have to hide and show button  as per login usertype.Here if login user is 'Visitor' then only show the rating button ow in any condition like may be user is admin or now any user without login condition is also there.
My code is work if usertype is 'Visitor' or 'Admin' but it fails when no one login. Actually that time this condition can not able to getting the type of user For that please help me I am not able to understand to handle this condition

```
<?php
if(!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
$user = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
  $userType = \Yii::$app->user->identity->type;
  echo ''.$userType;
  echo '<input type="text" value='.$userType.' id="usertype"/>';
} else {
  echo '<div>Div if user is not visitor</div>';
}
?>
```

**Script:**
script for hide and show the div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var userType= document.getElementById('usertype').value;

    if(userType == 'Visitor') {  
      $('#divUserRate').show();
    } else {  
      $('#divUserRate').hide();  
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isGuest` property from user model.

```
echo (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) ? '<div>Div if user is visitor</div>' : '<div>Div if user is not visitor</div>';
```

You can also use Rbac to manage roles and access.

```
if(Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess(Yii::$app->user->id, "editor"){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what exactly put in this <div> tag can you explain me using my javascript

Comment: replace it by your input tag `'<input type="text" value='.$userType.' id="usertype"/>'` .Its PHP not JS.

Comment: But..help me in one think my div is dynamic and in dynamic div button create dynamically and this button which i want to be hide this is also in dive after loading page only 1st button is hide other are not hide

Comment: I will attach image you understand better

Comment: open another question with some code.  Now I'm at work, when I have time try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For hide div.I have add class in button after that hide that class instead of div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btnRating').hide(); 
    $('#divliveventGallery').hide();
    var userType= document.getElementById('usertype').value;
    if(userType == 'Visitor' || userType == 'FB' || userType == 'GL') {  
      $('.btnRating').show(); 
    } else if(userType == 'Vendor'){ 
      $('.btnRating').hide();  
    } else if(userType == "") {
      $('.btnRating').hide(); 
    }
});
**************Button html**************
 echo '<button type="button" id="btnRate" onClick="rateDetail('.$dp['ven_id'].','.$userId.');" class=" btnRating btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rcrate">';
             echo '<strong>Rate</strong>';
             echo '</button> ';

</script>
```